Need feedback on PCB Power Distribution Board
I recently got tasked with designing a power distribution board incorporating the LM2596, a popular DC-DC buck converter/booster. Using a previous design as a reference, I followed a similar approach but would like some feedback.
In the previous design, the fuses were placed after the buck converter but before the output terminals. I opted to position the fuses before both the converter and the output terminals to protect both the converter and the peripheral device. Which placement is better?
Additionally, I considered adding a decoupling capacitor after the input terminal but decided against it, as it seemed potentially redundant given that all output terminals already pass through the converter.
Does this approach make sense?



The very thin track at fuse F4 may blow away faster than the fuse.

Are these the usual counterfeit "LM2596" modules that have spread all over the internet?

@Jens this has since been fixed but thank you for mentioning that.

@bobflux You are correct, however I have used a certain brands in the past and was very happy with the performance.

Maybe some brands are less garbage than others, but considering the low price of good quality DC-DCs... Do the capacitors get hot on your modules?

I do not believe so, for context I used the DC-DC to power a Raspberry Pi 4B. You can see the application here: https://github.com/msalaz03/ProjectClifford

Advantages to fusing after the DC-DC

You protect your expensive downstream equipment from more upstream failure (including the DC-DC itself)

Advantages to fusing before the DC-DC

Protects other DC-DCs from being brought low by a failure in one DC-DC
Blown fuse does not inject noise from low-draw on one DC-DC

Probably other considerations as well.  But make a list.  You could also have a single, larger fuse at the board input and individual fuses at the outputs.  But you would want to know what failure mode you are trying to protect against.
Clearly your board design is just starting but it is always a good idea to use fills for power channels, not thin traces.  Rotating your fuses 90° would allow you to have a ground channel and two V_in channels

Do you mind clarifying what you mean by using fills for power channels and not thin traces? What are you referring to in context to my board?

You currently have a ground fill in the middle of your board on F.Cu.  You don't appear to have connected the input power to your input fuses yet.  The VDD lines from your input fuse to the DCDC are very thin.  Similar your output lines are very thin.  You should use zone fills instead.
